# How are weight ranges mentioned for GA airplanes in TCDS?

Tags: general-aviation, weight-and-balance

I'm writing software to integrate a weight and balance chart into my website. Most of the [Type Certificate Data Sheets TCDS](http://www.airweb.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgMakeModel.nsf/MainFrame?OpenFrameSet) I've read follow the form:

*x* to *y* at *z* lbs. or less
*a* to *b* at *c* lbs.
Straight line variation between points given.

I want to make sure that I test this against more complex scenarios.  Are there general aviation aircraft that have more than 2 "ranges" or are otherwise exceptional that would make for good test cases?  I am only concerned with GA aircraft at this time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are there general aviation aircraft that have more than 2 "ranges"

Yes. [I happen to fly one (the PA-28 series, TCDS 2A13)](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgMakeModel.nsf/0/af90bd3d08b5d26e8625720a0054405a/$FILE/2A13.pdf).
The loading graphs look like this:

[image: PA28 loading graphs & ranges]

Note also that the aircraft is certificated in both the Normal and Utility category, and the weight/CG ranges are different (Utility being a subset of what's permissible for Normal category operations) - so there are two different operating envelopes that must be considered.

Comment: Awesome answer!  Thanks for taking the time to include the graphs.  This will make a great test scenario.

Comment: @dazedandconfused The Piper TCDS actually has the graphs in it, so it was just a cut-and-paste job. There are probably more complex examples out there, I just happen to know this one because I have to deal with the funny-shaped graph every time I work a W&B calculation. (I can't think of any aircraft which are not "straight-line variation" between the ranges offhand, so I think you can avoid having to do curve-fitting...)

Comment: This is actually very similar to most business jets that I have flown as well.